# Работа с вектором классов C++

Tags: c++, классы, vector

Дано: два вектора классов

```
vector <Unemployed> A;
vector <Vacancy> B;
```

Задание: смоделировать работу центра занятости на протяжении месяца, хочу перегрузить оператор сравнения `==` примерно так:

```
int operator==(Unemployed& a, Vacancy & b) {
  int i = 0;
  if (a.getSex() == b.getSex()) { i++; }    // пол
  if (a.getEduc() == b.getEduc()) { i++; }  // образование
  if (a.getAge() >= b.getAge()) { i++; }    // возрост
  if (a.getProf() == b.getProf()) { i++; }  // профессия
  if (a.getStaj() >= b.getStaj()) { i++; }  // стаж
  if (a.getWage() <= b.getWage()) { i++; }  // зарплата

  if (i == 6) {
    return 1;
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

В майне должно быть так:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {                  // кол-во недель
  for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {                // дни
    for (int k=0; k < B.at(i); k++) {      // из вакансии
      for (int n=0; n < A.at(i); n++) {    // из безработных
        B.at(i)==A.at(i);                  // найти и принять вакансию
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Есть ли способ как найти элемент обоих векторов и удалить их, чтобы принятая вакансия и рабочий не учитывались при следующей интерации. Или хотя бы идеи как можно сделать по другому, а то у меня фантазия уже кончилась)

Comment: Может, все-таки `if (i == 6) {`? А тут `B.at(i)=A.at(i);`?

Comment: @Harry oops, :)

Comment: И потом, кой смысл сравнивать **все**, и только потом решать? Делайте `if (a.getSex() != b.getSex()) return 0;` - такими строками, начиная со сравнений наиболее дешевых. Еще - передавайте в оператор **константные** ссылки. Вторая часть вопроса - от "в майне" - лично мне совершенно непонятна... :(

Comment: @Harry учту это, просто ночь не спал кодил))

Comment: @Harry первое что в голову пришло

Comment: @Harry так я как бы имитирую работу за месяц